# Bayesian posterior consistency when prior distribution is induced by a diffusion

Tags: st.statistics, bayesian-probability

Let $\Pi_{b,\sigma}$ be a  prior distribution on $\{z_t\}_{t<T}\in C_0[0,T]$ induced by the following diffusion:
\begin{align}
        d\tilde z_t&=b(\tilde z_t,t)dt+\sigma(\tilde z_t,t) dW_t, ~\text{ for $t<T$}.
    \end{align}
Let we observe $n$ i.i.d. samples at time $T$, denoted as $X_n^T$, from the model $P(\cdot|\{z_t\}_{t<T})$. Define the posterior distribution as the following Radon-Nikodym derivative
  \begin{align}
    \frac{d\Pi_{b,\sigma_0}(\{z_t\}_{t<T}|X_n^T)}{d\Pi_{b,\sigma}(\{z_t\}_{t<T})}= \frac{ P(X_n^T|\{z_t\}_{t<T}) }{\int d\Pi_{b,\sigma}(\{z_t\}_{t<T}) P(X_n^T|\{z_t\}_{t<T})}.
    \end{align}

Question
1. What is the notion of consistency of posterior distribution on $\{z_t\}_{t<T}$ as number of samples $n\to \infty$?
2. References to read more about such posteriors and their asymptotic properties.